# Removing the effect of Time series X on time series Y, when their relation is unknown

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression

I am working on a dataset of 6 years measurements of a water quality parameter called 'chla' ( parameter 'X') measured by a sensor for each year from May to October. The parameter has its own trend and irregular changes by month, day and even hour, but due to some proven biological theories, it also gets an inverse impact from solar radiation (parameter 'Y'), so that a daily periodicity effect can be observed on the data ( parameter 'X'). As a result, there is a periodical behavior in the parameter 'X' that starts from sunrise, maximizes in the noon and minimizes in sunset again and last to next sunrise. However, this effect is not very regular because some days or times are cloudy (low solar radiation).

My goal is to remove the effect of 'Y' on 'X'. I have the time series of both 'X' and 'Y' parameters sampled every 10 minutes. Is there any solution to remove the Y effect on X without knowing their exact mathematical relationship. the image below shows two images of parameters for a short time period.
cyan = parameter 'X' ; red = parameter 'Y'
[image]